# How winding number in a boundary point of a curve is defined?

Tags: complex-analysis, winding-number

We know that, the winding number counts the number of rounds of a curve
around a point. It is a positive integer for positive oriented curves and a negative integer
for curves with negative orientation. If the point a is enclosed by a simple closed rectifiable curve, then n(γ, a) = 1 and, if a is outside the curve, then n(γ, a) = 0.But if the point a is on the boundary of γ then what is n(γ, a) ?

Comment: It seems that you use $\gamma$ to denote "a simple closed rectifiable curve". Then it is unclear what you name "a boundary point" of the curve.

Comment: Looks like OP means a point on the curve, i.e., on the boundary of the enclosed region....

Comment: @Pratyay What does the definition in terms of an integral say (or fail to say)...?